# Weak limits with bounded nets II

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

This is a follow-up to a previous question that I forgot to add: [Weak limits with bounded nets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088401/weak-limits-with-bounded-nets/4088412#4088412).

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and suppose $\{\psi_{U}\}_{U\in \mathcal{U}}$ is a bounded net in $H$ such that $<v,\psi_{U}>$ converges for every $v\in H$. Why does this imply that $\{\psi_{U}\}$ converges weakly to some $\epsilon\in H$, i.e., that $<(\psi_{U}-\epsilon),v>\rightarrow 0$ for every $v\in H$?  Does it have something to the fact that the unit ball in $H$ is weakly compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection $\{f_U\}_U$ of linear functionals defined by $f_U(v)=\langle v,\psi_U\rangle$ is pointwise convergent. Define $f:=\lim f_U.$ It is easy to see that $f$ is linear. Now, since $\{\psi_U\}_U$ is bounded, $\sup_U\|f_U(v)\|\le \|v\|\|\psi_U\|<\infty$ so the Banach-Steinhaus theorem implies that $\sup_U\|f_U\|=M<\infty.$ Then, $\sup_{x\le 1}\|f(x)\|=\sup_{x\le 1}\|\lim f_U(x)\|<M$ so $f$ is continuous. That is, $f\in L(H).$ To finish, we may apply the Riesz theorem to find an $h\in H$ such that $f(v)=\langle v,h \rangle$ so that $\langle v,\psi_U\rangle\to \langle v,h \rangle.$